# Lipschitz property and wavelets

Tags: wavelets, lipschitz-functions

I'm trying to understand Nason et al(2000)'s proof of Proposition 3.3 in this paper: http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~guy/Research/papers/WavProcEWS1.pdf

The expectation of the uncorrected periodogram is given, and I don't fully understand the step after the substitution of $m=n+k$, where the use of property (10) and (12) gives $(w_{l,n+k;T})^2= S(\frac{n+k}{T})+O(T^{-1})$. I believe this is because the approximation to $|W_j(z)|^2$ is just $S(j)$ by property (12) and then property (10) gives that $W_j(\frac{k}{T})$ and $w_{j,k;T}$ only differ by a max of $\frac{C_j}{T}$. Thus they are saying $w_{l,n+k;T}^2=(W_l(\frac{n+k}{T})-W_l(\frac{n+k}{T})+w_{l,n+k,T})^2=[S(\frac{n+k}{T})+O(\frac{1}{T})]$? I am not sure at this point where the squared term disappears off to or if my interpretation is correct even up to this point.

Then assuming their line, I don't fully understand what the Lipschitz property has to do with the next equality? Can someone help me understand this?

Following the expansion of the terms I can follow the rest of the proof, as they are just the definitions provided by Nason et al(2000), but these steps are beyond my understanding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: At a glance: they are saying that since $W$ is Lipschitz, $S$ is also Lipschitz. Therefore  $|S_\ell((n+k)/T)-S_\ell(k/T)| = O(n/T)$.

Comment: Thanks! Then the only confusion I think I still have about this is: would the step above be correct in saying $O(\frac{1}{T^2})$, since we must be squaring the supremum of $\frac{C_j}{T}$ (and whatever terms come from the expansion of the squaring of $(W_l(\frac{n+k}{T})-W_l(\frac{n+k}{T})+w_{l,n+k,T})^2$)? Why is it still $O(\frac{1}{T})$?